# Scala: What is the most efficient way convert a Map[K,V] to an IntMap[V]?

Tags: scala, dictionary

Let"s say I have a class Point with a `toInt` method, and I have an immutable `Map[Point,V]`, for some type `V`. What is the most efficient way in Scala to convert it to an `IntMap[V]`? Here is my current implementation:

```
def pointMap2IntMap[T](points: Map[Point,T]): IntMap[T] = {
    var result: IntMap[T] = IntMap.empty[T]
    for(t <- points) {
        result += (t._1.toInt, t._2)
    }
    result
}
```

[EDIT] I meant primarily **faster**, but I would also be interested in shorter versions, even if they are not obviously faster.

Comment: Do you mean more efficient as in "better performance" (something that is extremely hard to gauge), or as in "less lines of code"?

Comment: It's hard to give a sufficient answer to this question without answer the previous question Jean posted, but also defining what IntMap[T] is -- it's easy enough to make assumptions about it, but some clarification would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IntMap` has a built-in factory method (`apply`) for this:

```
IntMap(points.map(p => (p._1.toInt, p._2)).toSeq: _*)
```

If speed is an issue, you may use:

```
points.foldLeft(IntMap.empty[T])((m, p) => m.updated(p._1.toInt, p._2))
```

Comment: I tried the built-in apply, but stumbled on the ".toSeq: _*" part. I like both your versions; they fit well on a single line. :)

Answer (score 1):

A one liner that uses `breakOut` to obtain an `IntMap`. It does a `map` to a new collection, using a custom builder factory `CanBuildFrom` which the `breakOut` call resolves:

```
Map[Int, String](1 -> "").map(kv => kv)(breakOut[Map[Int, String], (Int, String), immutable.IntMap[String]])
```

In terms of performance, it's hard to tell, but it creates a new `IntMap`, goes through all the bindings and adds them to the `IntMap`. A handwritten iterator `while` loop (preceded with a pattern match to check if the source map is an `IntMap`) would possibly result in somewhat better performance.

Comment: `breakOut` is unable to convert `Map[Point,T]` to `IntMap[T]` directly, so `Map[Int, String](1 -> "")` here is `points.map(p => (p._1.toInt, p._2))`, and it will require two mappings that way

Comment: I believe it can be done in a single map: `Map((1, 2) -> "").map(kv => (kv._1._1, kv._2))(breakOut[Map[(Int, Int), String], (Int, String), immutable.IntMap[String]])`

Comment: Type inference will allow you to avoid the explicit typing on breakOut: `def pointMap2IntMap[T](points: Map[Point, T]): IntMap[T] = points.map(kv => (kv._1.toInt, kv._2))(breakOut)`